# Apple/Android pay with multiple merchants

Tags: android-pay, applepay

I'm looking at build an app which will have support for apple/android pay. The services that users are buying are provided by third party merchants. Is it possible with android/apple pay to have support for a dynamic list of merchants in the app? The customers would walk into a store and user the device to pay using my app and the amount should be credited directly to the corresponding merchants account.

Or is it only possible to credit the amount to my account and later lay the merchant?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you mention walking into a store, but using your app - this is not how Android Pay works. If you want to accept payments in your app, there's no need to walk into a store. If you want to accept payments in a physical store, this is handled by the NFC payment terminal.

Comment: Yeah I'm talking about the physical store and NFC payment. Can our app get a callback once the payment is processed successfully even when the NFC terminal belongs to an individual merchant registered with us?

Comment: No, neither Android nor Apple Pay, to the best of my knowledge, have a way of sharing transaction data. The only way to do this would be to integrate with the merchant and have them send you the notification.